# How to fix the distance between horizontal points (x-axis) in chartJS

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js, chart.js2

**Problem:** Hi all! i am using chart.js to draw the charts. chart is a dynamic sometimes shows 10 points and sometimes can be more than thousand i have applied a panel successfully so that my points can be shown at some distance to read them easily.

Right now i want to know if there is any option to set the distance between points in x-axis grid. right now it automatically adjust the points.

**What i tried:**
i tried to do the stepsize and scalewidth by searching other stackoverflow answers but did not succeed. Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

P.S:  i m using chart.js2

This is my chartjs dataset

```
var data = {
    labels: data.graph_date,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Assay Values',
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0,1)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0,1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 1,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: data.assay_value,
            spanGaps: false
        },var options = {
    responsive: false,
    title: {
        display: true,
        position: "top",
        text: label,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontColor: "#111"
    },
    legend: {
        display: true,
        position: "bottom",
        labels: {
            fontColor: "#333",
            fontSize: 16
        }
    },
    tooltips: {
        enabled: true,
        mode: 'single',
        callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                var multistringText = ['Assay Value: '+tooltipItems.yLabel];
                multistringText.push('Assigned Value: '+assigned_value[tooltipItems.index]);
                multistringText.push('Sample ID: '+sample_id[tooltipItems.index]);
                return multistringText;
            }
        }
    },
    scales:{
        yAxes:[{
            ticks:{
                min:graph_min
            }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display:false
            }
        }]
    }
};
if(new_chart[ctx.canvas.id] != null)
    new_chart[ctx.canvas.id].destroy();

new_chart[ctx.canvas.id] =new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

In x-axis there is data like this

```
[19-Aug-2015,21-Aug-2015,21-Aug-2015,21-Aug-2015,21-Aug-2015,22-Aug-2015,27-Aug-2015,29-Aug-2015,1-Sep-2015,2-Sep-2015,3-Sep-2015,]
```

in y-axis data is like this

```
[0.1,0.05,0.89,0.89,0.79,0.58,0.68,0.25,0.98]
```

Comment: stepSize does work, what do you mean you did not suceed?

Comment: kristjan it did not work on xaxis it only work to the yaxis

Comment: Can you post your entire chart.js config and a sample of your data?  This is what is needed to provide a specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way to control distance between points it to set the X and Y axis with a min, max, and step size so that they never change regardless of the number of points that are in the chart.

Here is an example that sets the scales so that they will never change.  Regardless of how many points appear on the chart everything will stay the same.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Points',
      data: [
        {x: 0, y: 2},
        {x: 1, y: 3}, 
        {x: 2, y: 2},
        {x: 1.02, y: 0.4},
        {x: 0, y: -1}
      ],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(123, 83, 252, 0.8)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(33, 232, 234, 1)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      fill: false,
      showLine: false,
    }],
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js - Fixed X and Y Axis',
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'bottom',
        ticks: {
          min: -1,
          max: 8,
          stepSize: 1,
          fixedStepSize: 1,
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: -2,
          max: 4,
          stepSize: 1,
          fixedStepSize: 1,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/MpzgqQ) that demonstrates what this looks like

Comment: i see your example here. Problem is i m not showing the numbers on the y-axes there are dates which are showing. so it did not consider numeric value like min and max

Comment: In the future, be sure to include important details like that in your question.   Since you are dealing with dates, I assume you are using the time scale?  If so, the time scale has a [min/max](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-time-scale) value as well.  Use it the same way as my example.  If you are interested I can update my answer using time scale instead.

Comment: pardon this mistake. Yes i m using date but not the time  scale function of chartjs actually the values are coming from database. let me add the code

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look!

Comment: I saw that.  Can you post your full chart.js config and a small sample of your data?  That will prevent me making any assumptions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139387/discussion-between-jordanwillis-and-adeel).